# Permanently filter a SQLAlchemy relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a User model that belongs to multiple Groups through a GroupMember association model.  I use soft deletes, so currently `user.groups` can include deleted groups.  Is there a permanent filter I can apply to a relationship so it does not include the deleted instances?

```
class User(Base):
    # ...
    groups = relationship(
        'group',
        secondary=GroupMember.__table__,
        order_by=GroupMember.position
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the join condition for the relationship by specifying `primaryjoin`.

```
groups = relationship(
    Group, GroupMemeber.__table__,
    primaryjoin=lambda: and_(not_(Group.deleted), GroupMemeber.user_id == User.id)
)
```

Note that this doesn't prevent you from adding deleted groups to a member.  SQLAlchemy doesn't know what `primaryjoin` is doing, it only knows the basic relationship between the models.  SQLAlchemy also won't remove associations when the `primaryjoin` condition is no longer true.  In order to see the *actual* collection of groups associated with a member, it would be useful to have a second `all_groups` relationship.